# Upper bound for moment of the Riemann zeta function

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, moments

Is it possible to get a good upper bound for the integral $$\int_{0}^{T}\zeta ^{3}(\frac{1}{3}+it)dt$$ (unconditionally)?

Comment: $=T+O(1)-i\int_{2+iT}^{1/3+iT} \zeta^3(s)ds$, there is the trivial bound $\zeta^3(s)=O(s^3)$, which can be improved a lot with the partial results toward the Lindelof hypothesis extended to the whole critical strip with Hadamard 3 lines theorem.

Comment: You can improve it further by writing $\left|\int \zeta^3\right|\leq |\zeta|\cdot \int |\zeta|^2$ and using $L^2$ bounds on $\zeta$ on vertical lines together with subconvexity bounds on $\zeta$.

Comment: Reuns' contour shifting means one is now integrating on horizontal lines rather than vertical lines, so the L^2 mean value theorem is no longer of much use (and applying it before contour shifting would destroy too much cancellation to give a strong bound).

Comment: @reuns  I think you meant to write $O(T)$ instead of $T$. Is it the term corresponding to $\int_0^T \zeta^3 (2+it) dt$?

Comment: @SungjinKim Direct calculation gives $\int_0^T \zeta^3(2+it)\ dt = T + \sum_{n=2}^\infty \frac{d_3(n) (1-n^{-iT})}{i n^2 \log n} = T + O(1)$.

Comment: @TerryTao Thank you. Then by $\zeta(1/2+it)=O( (|t|+2)^{1/6})$, we obtain $\int_0^T \zeta^3(1/3+it) dt = T+O(T^{5/6})$.